# Rails: controller cannot recognize class from module/namespace - uninitialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've created directory for API logic: app/api/EtherumAPI/V1 and put there following code:

```
module EtherumAPI
    module V1
        class Request


            class << self
                def trancation
                end 
            end
        end 
    end
end
```

Registered in my application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/api"
config.eager_load_paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/api"
```

And try to call it inside my controller:

```
  def index
    @test = EtherumAPI::V1::Request
    @test.trancation
  end
```

But I got this error:

> uninitialized constant HomeController::EtherumAPI

I tried also something like "include EtherumAPI::V1" but it didn't succeed as well. How can I fix it and be able to call methods from Request class?

Comment: Try doing `::EtherumAPI::V1::Request`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off you can get rid of:

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/api"
config.eager_load_paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/api"
```

All the subdirectories of `app` are by default auto-load paths. Occasionally the auto-loader gets "stuck" and will not pick up newly added directories. You can usually fix that by restarting the rails server and spring (`$ spring stop`).

There are two issues at play here. The first is inflection. Rails inflects file names from classes by camelizing the class name. Unfortunately this does not work automatically for acronyms as `ABC` -> `a_b_c.rb`.

So for the autoloader to look for EtherumAPI in `etherum_api.rb` you need to add an inflection:

```
# config/initializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'EtherumAPI'
end
```

The second issue is that the module names must match the actual path to the file.

```
# app/api/etherum_api/v1/request.rb
module EtherumAPI
    module V1
        class Request
            class << self
                def trancation
                end 
            end
        end 
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for such complex answer. I did just like you said. Get rid off config autoload lines add Inflector and rename my directories. However it's not working anyway. I also tried to require that file manually in my controller and  Rails rise no errors. But then calling my methods I get no feedback. I mean when I call EtherumAPI::V1::Request.transation and put something like "Hello World" inside transation method the string do not appear in my console.

Comment: In other words: when I require manually and type EtherumAPI::V1::Request.transation.inspect I get no errors but the output is nil.

Comment: But it is actually getting auto-loaded since you are not getting a uninitialized constant error. Have you reloaded (`reload!`) the class in the console after changing your code? Could it be caused by the usual slop errors (file not saved, changing the wrong file etc)?

Comment: Right. It was probably reloading isssue. Now it's working fine.